# how to have ruby console recognize code changes in controllers and models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm adding new functionality to my ruby model and testing it through the ruby console as I go. I find it very annoying to have to restart the console everytime I change anything in the model. Is there a way to have the ruby console not cache or have it check for updated code without restarting it?

For example, I'm making a new method in the model, and after I make a change, I have to restart the console and run a few commands to load everything back up again. See below:

```
script/console
require 'some_gem'
r = Region.find_by_name("some_region")
r.some_method
```

If I change a line in the high_x method from the region model, I have to repeat all of the steps to see my change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just type:

```
reload!
```

This will ... reload :)

Comment: However, existing objects don't seem to pick up the changes

Comment: What if you reload the object as well: @object.reload